# Spring security does not find users

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have following code for `Spring Security version 3.2.3.RELEASE`, that shows a custom login page. I enter correct username and passwords but it returns `Invalid username and password`.

Hibernate is working as it shows Schema gets updated.

```
Oct 24, 2015 5:12:54 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Oct 24, 2015 5:12:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 24, 2015 5:12:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 24, 2015 5:12:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15276 ms
```

param.errr `${param.error}` is 1.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
                        Invalid username and password.
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                        <div class="error">${error}</div>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
                    </c:if>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="form-login" role="form" method="post" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />"
class="relative form form-default"> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                                value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

**WEB.XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>pr</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<listener>  
  <listener-class>  
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener  
        </listener-class>  
 </listener>  

 <context-param>  
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
  <param-value>  
   /WEB-INF/config/spring-security.xml  
  </param-value>  
 </context-param>  

 <welcome-file-list>  
  <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>  
 </welcome-file-list>  

 <!-- Spring Security -->  
 <filter>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
 </filter>  

 <filter-mapping>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
 </filter-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

**my-servlet.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/index" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/aboutus" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/signin" />



    <mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" />
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Config -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/myProject" />
        <property name="username" value="daniel" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        depends-on="dataSource">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- End Hibernate Config -->
</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">



    <beans:import resource='login-service.xml' />
    <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/notFound.jsp"
        use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />


        <form-login login-page="/signin" default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/signin?error=1" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />

        <!-- <remember-me /> -->
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <csrf />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="
              select username,password,enabled 
              from Member where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="
                      select username 
                      from Member where username = ?"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**login-service.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myProject" />
        <property name="username" value="daniel" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**member.java**

```
@Entity
public class Member implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 31689851531929707L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String authority;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String fname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short gender;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean availability;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date registrationDate;

    getters and setters

}
```

**Update**

I added `user-service` to avoid database but I am still receiving same error.

```
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service> <user name="admin@myproject.com" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/> 
                <user name="user@yahoo.com" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER"/> </user-service> 
<!--            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" -->

<!--                users-by-username-query=" -->
<!--              select username,password,enabled  -->
<!--              from Member where username=?" -->

<!--                authorities-by-username-query=" -->
<!--                       select username  -->
<!--                       from Member where username=?" /> -->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Also I used following code and **even before submitting the form** I am receiving following output.

```
Your login attempt was not successful due to

Bad credentials.




 <c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">
      <font color="red">
        Your login attempt was not successful due to <br/><br/>
        <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>.
      </font>
</c:if>
```

Comment: You authorities-by-username query seems wrong, it always returns the username.

Comment: And try to debug Spring's authmanager to see what is happening.

Comment: @IvanNemeth how to do that? I used static username passwords but it still does not work. I updated the question.

Comment: You need more information about the concrete authexception thrown, Spring has many different exception types, but you only see that something went wrong. Isn't any stacktrace in the log files? If not, try to configure log, or you can debug it with a Java IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: Just a tip, but if you receive it before submitting the form, it means that it tries to authenticate with an empty user somehow. BadCredentials is thrown not only when the password is wrong, but when the user is not found, in your example when it is null or empty string. So the auth filter is somehow applied to your login page but it shouldn't. Unfortunately I'm not so familiar with this kind of spring config.